# How can I build a date from 3 columns of float datatype?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have a table (t1) which has the following 3 columns:

```
DAY   MONTH    YEAR
 2      11     2021
 1      10     2021
 12     10     2021
 22     09     2021
```

All the 3 columns have a float datatype.

What would be the t-sql code to build a date from these 3 columns in the following format (YYYY-MM-DD):

```
CREATEDDATE
2021-11-02
2021-10-01
2021-10-12
2021-09-22
```

I have tried looking around for other questions similar to mine but I could not find a solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [`DATEFROMPARTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Though, I will admit, `float` is a poor choice of data type for 3 columns whose value only hold an integer; 2 of which must be be `<= 31` and the other `< 10000`. `tinyint` and `smallint` would be far more appropriate values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DATEFROMPARTS()` function is an option (*... returns a date value that maps to the specified year, month, and day values*):

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS([YEAR], [MONTH], [DAY]) AS CREATEDATE
FROM (VALUES
    (2,  11, 2021),
    (1,  10, 2021),
    (12, 10, 2021),
    (22, 09, 2021)
) t ([DAY], [MONTH], [YEAR])
```

Or with the actual table:

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS([YEAR], [MONTH], [DAY]) AS CREATEDATE
FROM t1
```

Comment: Thanks. However, should the values be hard coded? The table contains more than 100 rows.

Comment: @user3115933, it's only to generate the test data. Use `... FROM Yourtable ... ` instead.